# Is there an R function to create a raw string based on an existing object?

Tags: r

I am creating a filepath to read in R through a hard coded raw string (because otherwise the filepath raises an error):

```
filepath <- r"(C:\User\me\folder\data)"
```

However, I would like to create the following functionality to prevent the user from writing directly the filepath within the raw string:

```
filepath <- "C:\User\me\folder\data"
# I know the as_raw function doesn't exist, but I am wondering whether there is something similar
filepath <- as_raw(filepath)
```

Is there any R function that does this? Or should the user always modify the raw string (or use a readline function)?

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want to achieve, you are asking for a function, let's call it, `as_raw` that exactly does what the `r` function in you initial code does. As the backslash needs to be escaped, the user won't be able to submit a filepath with backslahes. Alternative is to just ask for the part behind the user name or submit the folder with two forward slashes.

Comment: I don't think there is one. `filepath <- "C:\User\me\folder\data"` raises an error due to the invalid character value.

Comment: @deschen I was wondering whether there was any way to avoid the error while still reading the same filepath, in order to make it as user-friendly as possible (i.e., avoiding the user from typing the filepath within the raw string, since they might mistype the raw string). However, it looks like it won't be possible to write the filepath as in the second chunk without raising an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of these could be used:

```
filepath <- "C:/User/me/folder/data"

filepath <- "C:\\User\\me\\folder\\data"

filepath <- file.path("C:", "User", "me", "folder", "data")

filepath <- file.choose() # if file exists.  Interactive.

filepath <- choose.dir() # same but for directory

filepath <- readClipboard() # if filepath is on clipboard. \ is ok.

filepath <- r"(C:\User\me\folder\data)"
```

Comment: All of them are really useful, I would also add:


`filepath <- readline("Paste your file path here:")`. However, it looks like there isn't any option to directly create an object from the raw file path from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could either ask the user to submit a file path with two forward slashes:

```
filepath <- "C://User//me//folder//data"
```

Or you can just ask for the part after the user name and then glue it together with the user path:

```
folder <- "folder//data"

filepath <- paste0("C://Users//", Sys.info()["user"], "//", folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
charToRaw(filepath)
```

Should do what you want, I think.

Comment: This could be useful, however, I don't want to transform the filepath into raw format, just to a raw string format.